# Is there a MAX_INT constant in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, integer, constants

In Java I can say `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to get the largest number that the `int` type can hold.

Is there a similar constant/function in Postgres? I'd like to avoid hard-coding the number.

Edit: the reason I am asking is this. There is a legacy table with an ID of type `integer`, backed by a sequence. There is a lot of incoming rows into this table. I want to calculate how much time before the `integer` runs out, so I need to know "how many IDs are left" divided by "how fast we are spending them".

Comment: No there is no such constant Where should that be? There are no pre-defined "classes" such as `Integer` in a database. If you want you can write a function that simply returns 2147483647

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, there are plenty of predefined and magic constants in SQL, including postgres: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, for instance. It wouldn't seem at all out of place to me to have a `MAX_INT` / `INT_MAX`. Or, for that matter, a C-style `sizeof()` function.

Comment: None of those predefined functions in SQL expose _implementation_  details. SQL doesn't really deal with low level information like `sizeof()` because the goal of SQL is to relieve you from the need to know that. You can query for the size of a _value_, but not for the size of data type. The real question is: why do you think you need that? What is the underlying problem that you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited to add the reason for my question.

Comment: Why don't you just change the column to `bigint`? But to check if you are "running" out you can just use a hardcoded value. That is not going to change any time soon.

Comment: Unfortunately, "legacy" means switching to `bigint` is expensive and will be postponed if not necessary. Hence the "running out" check. Best programming practices ask to use a constant if one is available, hence the questions :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no constant for this, but I think it's more reasonable to hard-code the number in Postgres than it is in Java.

In Java, the philosophical goal is for `Integer` to be an abstract value, so it makes sense that you'd want to behave as if you don't know what the max value is.

In Postgres, you're much closer to the bare metal and the definition of the `integer` type is that it is [a 4-byte signed integer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html).

Comment: The size of an int is also abstracted in C, which Postgres is written in.

Comment: A Postgres `integer` is not the same as a C `int`

Comment: Yes. Sorry, didn't mean to say it is abstracted in Postgres. Postgres defines their integer limits independently.

Comment: I think you misunderstand Java, making `int` 4 bytes was one of their core design decisions, because (AFAIK) they didn't want any of the cruft associated with differing sizes of `int`s in C/C++ (which is actually due to the variety of CPU architectures that C/C++ compilers have been written for).  If Java intended for `int` to be an abstract value they wouldn't have `long`s and `short`s etc.

Answer (score 3):

> There is a legacy table with an ID of type integer, backed by a sequence.

In that case, you can get the max value of the sequence by:
`select seqmax from pg_sequence where seqrelid = 'your_sequence_name'::regclass`.
This might be better than getting the MAX_INT, because sequence may have been created/altered with a specific max value that is different from MAX_INT.